# How can I write csv.DictReader JSON structure back to TSV file via csv.DictWriter?

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I'm creating a python (Flask) application that will be deployed to a **read-only file system** in production. Overall, this application intends to:

1. Parse a .TSV as a list of dictionaries (using the `csv.DictReader`) in a wrapper python script (`main.py`)
2. Turn that list into a JSON structure (still `main.py`)
3. Pass this JSON structure to another python script (`author-script.py`) as an argument in the command-line (since I can't save the .TSV file locally in production)
4. Parse the JSON structure and write out to a temp TSV file in memory (now in `author-script.py`)
5. Process that TSV file to produce an HTML file as a result (`author-script.py`)

For Step 4) I want the `author-script.py` script to parse this JSON structure ultimately like a .TSV file via `csv.DictWriter`. This is because, originally, `author-script.py` is set up to parse a TSV file and it would take too long to modify it so that it parses a dictionary.

Currently, my approach for doing this is to backtrack from the JSON structure back to dictionaries and then write these out via `csv.DictWriter`. Below is my attempt (demo-ing as if I'm starting within `author-script.py` to parse the JSON structure argument):

```
import csv
import json
from pprint import pprint
from ast import literal_eval

# This is the JSON structure that's passed to the python script
infile = '"[{\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Anna\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Karenina\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8885006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Places\\": \\"BioInform_Harvard\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8885006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"1\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"anna.Karenina@ucsf.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Konstantin\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Levin\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8887006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"Neuro_Harvard\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8887006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"1\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Konstantin.levin@childrens.harvard.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"D\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Alexei\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Vronsky\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8889006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Places\\": \\"IGM_Columbia\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8889006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"2\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"alexei.vronsky@cumc.columbia.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"K\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Stepan\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Oblonsky\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8891006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"NIMH\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8891006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"2\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"steoblon@mail.nih.gov\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Ekaterina\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Shcherbatskaya\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8893006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"CHU_Montreal\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8893006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Ekaterina.Shcherbatskaya@umontreal.ca\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Alexei\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Karenin\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8895006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"BioInform_Harvard, Neuro_Harvard\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8895006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Karenin05@hms.harvard.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Fyodor\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Dostoevsky\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8897006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"Penn_Psych\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8897006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Fyodor_Dostoevsky@pennmedicine.upenn.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"M\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Lev\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Tolstoy\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8899006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"UCSF_Weill\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8899006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Email\\": \\"ltolstoy@mednet.ucla.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"N\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Place\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Address\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"BioInform_Harvard\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Biomedical Informatics, Harvard Medical School, Boston, MA, USA\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"CHU_Montreal\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"CHU Sainte-Justine Research Centre, University of Montreal, 3175 Chemin de la Co_te-Sainte-Catherine, Montreal, Quebec H3T 1C5, Canada.\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"IGM_Columbia\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Institute for Genomic Medicine, Columbia University Medical Center, Hammer Health Sciences, 1408, 701 West 168th St., New York, NY 10032, USA.\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Neuro_Harvard\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Neurology, Boston Children\'s Hospital and Harvard Medical School, Boston, MA, USA\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"NIMH\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"National Institute of Mental Health, 10 Center Dr, Bethesda, MD 20814\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Penn_Psych\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Psychiatry, Neuropsychiatry Section, Perelman School of Medicine at the University of Pennsylvania, 3400 Spruce, Philadelphia, PA 19104\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"UCSF_Weill\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Psychiatry, UCSF Weill Institute for Neurosciences, University of California, San Francisco, San Francisco, CA 94158\\"}]"'

# Convert json string that's passed to script into literal list of dicts
contents = literal_eval(json.loads(infile))

# Put list of dicts back into TSV "file" in memory
writer = csv.DictWriter(open("dict_write_test.tsv", 'w'), fieldnames=None, delimiter='\t')
for l in contents:
    writer.writerow(l)
```

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable`. I know how to make this work if I had the `csv.DictReader` object in the same script, but I wouldn't have that in this case.

**My questions are**:

1. How exactly do I convert from JSON --> dictionaries --> DictReader object --> DictWriter --> TSV file?
2. How do I write out to the .TSV file **in memory**?

**UPDATE**

When I test the following method by having the `csv.DictReader` object in the same code, the `csv.DictWriter` method obviously works fine and prints out the TSV file in memory as it looked in the original TSV. But when I implement @martineau's solution, the columns are outputted in a jumbled manner.

```
infile = open("/Users/cdastmalchi/Downloads/Author_Template.tsv")

contents = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter='\t')
memory_file = io.StringIO()

writer = csv.DictWriter(memory_file, fieldnames=contents.fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
for row in contents:
    writer.writerow(row)

as_string = memory_file.getvalue()
print('\n'.join(as_string.splitlines()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the error because you have `fieldnames=None` in the `csv.DictWriter()` call. You can get the fieldnames from the keys of the first dictionary in the `contents` list.

The TSV file can be written to memory by using the [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) class.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import csv
import json
import io
from pprint import pprint

# This is the JSON structure that's passed to the python script
infile = '"[{\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Anna\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Karenina\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8885006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Places\\": \\"BioInform_Harvard\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8885006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"1\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"anna.Karenina@ucsf.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Konstantin\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Levin\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8887006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"Neuro_Harvard\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8887006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"1\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Konstantin.levin@childrens.harvard.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"D\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Alexei\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Vronsky\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8889006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Places\\": \\"IGM_Columbia\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8889006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"2\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"alexei.vronsky@cumc.columbia.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"K\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Stepan\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Oblonsky\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8891006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"NIMH\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8891006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"2\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"steoblon@mail.nih.gov\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Ekaterina\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Shcherbatskaya\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8893006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"CHU_Montreal\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8893006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Ekaterina.Shcherbatskaya@umontreal.ca\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Alexei\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Karenin\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8895006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"BioInform_Harvard, Neuro_Harvard\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8895006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Karenin05@hms.harvard.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"A\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Fyodor\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Dostoevsky\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8897006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"Penn_Psych\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8897006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Email\\": \\"Fyodor_Dostoevsky@pennmedicine.upenn.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"M\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"Y\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Lev\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"Tolstoy\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"8899006000\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"UCSF_Weill\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"8899006001\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"Y\\", \\"Email\\": \\"ltolstoy@mednet.ucla.edu\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"N\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Place\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Address\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"BioInform_Harvard\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Biomedical Informatics, Harvard Medical School, Boston, MA, USA\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"CHU_Montreal\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"CHU Sainte-Justine Research Centre, University of Montreal, 3175 Chemin de la Co_te-Sainte-Catherine, Montreal, Quebec H3T 1C5, Canada.\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"IGM_Columbia\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Institute for Genomic Medicine, Columbia University Medical Center, Hammer Health Sciences, 1408, 701 West 168th St., New York, NY 10032, USA.\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Neuro_Harvard\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Neurology, Boston Children\'s Hospital and Harvard Medical School, Boston, MA, USA\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"NIMH\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"National Institute of Mental Health, 10 Center Dr, Bethesda, MD 20814\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"Penn_Psych\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Psychiatry, Neuropsychiatry Section, Perelman School of Medicine at the University of Pennsylvania, 3400 Spruce, Philadelphia, PA 19104\\"}, {\\"Manuscript preparation\\": \\"\\", \\"First_Name\\": \\"UCSF_Weill\\", \\"Last_Name\\": \\"\\", \\"Tel\\": \\"\\", \\"Data generation\\": \\"\\", \\"Places\\": \\"\\", \\"Fax\\": \\"\\", \\"Experimental design\\": \\"\\", \\"Joint\\": \\"\\", \\"Data analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Statistical analysis\\": \\"\\", \\"Data processing\\": \\"\\", \\"Corresponding\\": \\"\\", \\"Email\\": \\"\\", \\"Initials\\": \\"Department of Psychiatry, UCSF Weill Institute for Neurosciences, University of California, San Francisco, San Francisco, CA 94158\\"}]"'

# Convert json string that's passed to script into literal list of dicts
contents = json.loads(literal_eval(infile))
fieldnames = contents[0].keys()  # Get TSV fieldnames from first dictionary.

# Put list of dicts back into TSV "file" in memory
memory_file = io.StringIO()
writer = csv.DictWriter(memory_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerows(contents)

as_string = memory_file.getvalue()
print('\n'.join(as_string.splitlines()))
```

You may have problems passing the file as a command-line argument if the file is very big.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! When I try the above, I get the error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_csv.py", line 20, in <module>
    writer.writerows(contents)
  File "/Users/cdastmalchi/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 158, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(rows)
TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'`

Comment: @claudiadast: Looks like you're using Python 2. The code in my answer was written for Python 3.x. You should tag your question "python-2.x".

Comment: Ahh, yes you're right! It works with python 3. The only problem is that the columns are all jumbled up

Comment: @claudiadast: Please tag your question "python-3.x" if that's what you want. Obviously it matters.

Comment: please see my update. I was about to mark your answer as the correct one, but I still have the issue of the columns not being in the original order as they would be if I used the code in my update. (Unfortunately, in my case, I can't have the DictReader and DictWriter object in the same script).

Comment: @claudiadas: The data is jumbled in the `infile` string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196535/discussion-between-claudiadast-and-martineau).